# Android studio showing toolbar even though theme is set to theme.appcompat.light.noactionbar

Tags: android-studio

In my project I selected `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as the base theme, but in the Android Studio layout editor preview, it is showing a white toolbar with the activity name like this screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

This the style declared in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

But in the emulator it is not showing the toolbar. Anyone know why it is showing like this or a way to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know, it can be considered as answer. But this is how i fixed it. It happened after i updated sdk to v22. Change the version of device shown in preview from 22 to 21.

[image: Answer]